# form isn't shown when relationship is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a relationship like this

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :setting
end
```

and the setting class

```
class Setting
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :user

  field :notify, type: Boolean
end
```

and I have a form like this:

```
<% form_for current_user.setting || current_user.build_setting, :html => {:class => 'well'} do |f| %>
  Notificar: <%= f.check_box :notify, :class => 'check' %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Salvar" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but when I access the form page, the form isn't shown. I suspect that it's because `setting` is nil, or something like that...
What am I missing?
Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an equal sign in front of `form_for`.

```
<%= form_for # ... %>
```

The `form_for` helper renders all the stuff in its block, adds a form tag and returns the html. In order to display it, you have to tell eRB you want to display the returned string. So when the equal sign is missing, it will just not display the output.

Comment: ow lawd, you're right. worked. and thanks for the explanation :)